How to install a downloaded LibreOffice 24.2.3?
After downloading and extracting libreoffice and going to ~/Downloads/tmp/LibreOffice_24.2.3.2_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEB, I encoutered this issue. How do I overcome them on Ubuntu 22.04? I can't install any of these files.
$ ls
libobasis24.2-base_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                                  libobasis24.2-images_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                  libobasis24.2-xsltfilter_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-calc_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                                  libobasis24.2-impress_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                 libreoffice24.2_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-core_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                                  libobasis24.2-kde-integration_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb         libreoffice24.2-base_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-draw_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                                  libobasis24.2-librelogo_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb               libreoffice24.2-calc_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-en-us_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                                 libobasis24.2-libreofficekit-data_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb     libreoffice24.2-debian-menus_24.2.3-2_all.deb
libobasis24.2-extension-beanshell-script-provider_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb   libobasis24.2-math_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                    libreoffice24.2-dict-en_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-extension-javascript-script-provider_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb  libobasis24.2-ogltrans_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                libreoffice24.2-dict-es_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-extension-mediawiki-publisher_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb         libobasis24.2-onlineupdate_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb            libreoffice24.2-dict-fr_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-extension-nlpsolver_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                   libobasis24.2-ooofonts_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                libreoffice24.2-draw_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-extension-pdf-import_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                  libobasis24.2-ooolinguistic_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb           libreoffice24.2-en-us_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-extension-report-builder_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb              libobasis24.2-postgresql-sdbc_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb         libreoffice24.2-impress_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-firebird_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                              libobasis24.2-python-script-provider_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb  libreoffice24.2-math_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-gnome-integration_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                     libobasis24.2-pyuno_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                   libreoffice24.2-ure_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb
libobasis24.2-graphicfilter_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                         libobasis24.2-writer_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb                  libreoffice24.2-writer_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i libreoffice24.2-base_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package libreoffice24.2-base.
(Reading database ... 520086 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libreoffice24.2-base_24.2.3.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice24.2-base (24.2.3.2-2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice24.2-base:
 libreoffice24.2-base depends on libreoffice24.2 (>= 24.2.3.2); however:
  Package libreoffice24.2 is not installed.
 libreoffice24.2-base depends on libreoffice24.2 (<= 24.2.3.2-2); however:
  Package libreoffice24.2 is not installed.
 libreoffice24.2-base depends on libobasis24.2-base (>= 24.2.3.2); however:
  Package libobasis24.2-base is not installed.
 libreoffice24.2-base depends on libobasis24.2-base (<= 24.2.3.2-2); however:
  Package libobasis24.2-base is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice24.2-base (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice24.2-base


Why not install the tested, verified version from the official Ubuntu repos?

Reading the installation instructions might be helpful.

You can install all of the .deb files and their additional dependencies with
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt -f install

However, I would recommend to use the official Libreoffice PPA instead.
Why? Automatic updates in the update manager+dependencies taken care off.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libreoffice


sudo dpkg -i *.deb worked

Please keep in mind that software installed from ppa's will not get updated by unattended upgrades unless configured to do so.

@mook765 By automatic updates, I meant you don't have to go to a website to search for the update. The update manager will take care of libreoffice as well as other apt apps
